# What is the different between forEach and for loop in angular 2/4 or Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

**for loop**

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedFileType.length; i++) {
  console.log(this.selectedFileType[i]);
}
```

**forEach**

```
this.selectedFileType.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(item);
});
```

When I am run this code the same thing happen. I want to know is there any difference of compiling time difference.

Comment: See also why Angular team prefers loop over forEach https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render3/PERF_NOTES.md#loops

Comment: Typescript is a superset of JavaScript. And your question seems to be more of JavaScript question rather than Angular/Typescript related question, as apart from `this` keyword it has nothing to with Angular/Typescript.